# Error while importing data from MongoDb to Hdfs

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop

I'm trying to import documents of a collection in MongoDb to HDFS through MapReduce job. I am using old Api. This is the driver code

```html
package my.pac;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil;

public class ImportDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new ImportDriver(), args);
  System.exit(exitCode);
 }
 @Override
 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JobConf conf = new JobConf();
  MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(conf,"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SampleDb.shows");
        conf.setJarByClass(ImportDriver.class);
  conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/conf/core-site.xml"));
  conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
  conf.setInputFormat(MongoInputFormat.class);
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
  conf.setMapperClass(ImportMapper.class);
  conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  JobClient.runJob(conf);
  return 0;
 }
}
```

This is my Mapper Code:

```html
package my.pac;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable;

public class ImportMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<BSONWritable, BSONWritable, Text, Text>{

 @Override
 public void map(BSONWritable key, BSONWritable value,
   OutputCollector<Text, Text> o, Reporter arg3)
   throws IOException {
  String val = ((BSONObject) value).get("_id").toString();
  System.out.println(val);
  
  o.collect( new Text(val), new Text(val));
  
 }

}
```

I am using

1. Ubuntu-14.0
2. Hadoop-1.2.1
3. MongoDb-3.0.4

I have added the following jars:

1. mongo-2.9.3.jar
2. mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.0.jar
3. mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar

When I run this, I am getting an error like this :

```html
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject
 at my.pac.ImportMapper.map(ImportMapper.java:18)
 at my.pac.ImportMapper.map(ImportMapper.java:1)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all the jars I used are correct. The way I tried getting data out of BSONWritable was wrong. I tried to cast BSONWritable to BSONObject, which cannot be casted. Here is how I solved the problem.

```
        String name = (String)value.getDoc().get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have an outdated driver in your classpath that's causing the conflict in read preference settings.

See below links for similar issues:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-849

https://serverfault.com/questions/268953/mongodb-java-r2-5-3-nosuchmethoderror-on-dbcollection-savedbobject-in-tomca

If that doesn't help,
https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TBD-1002
suggests you may need to re-run MongoDB or use a separate connection.